# Will derived state be allowed for React Concurrent Mode?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, react-state-management, getderivedstatefromprops, react-concurrent

Today we can use [`getDerivedStateFromProps`](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#static-getderivedstatefromprops) for class components and [state updates during render phase](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-faq.html#how-do-i-implement-getderivedstatefromprops) for React Hooks/function components to create derived state, if needed.

I am especially curious about the React Hook variant: Will this be allowed in React Concurrent Mode?

If I wrap the `ScrollView` component from the FAQ with [StrictMode](https://reactjs.org/docs/strict-mode.html) `<React.StrictMode>...</React.StrictMode>`, there will be no warnings. However, I still have a slight feeling in stomach, this pattern could be problematic with concurrent mode.

So question is:

Is derived state still possible in React Concurrent Mode with regard to the Hooks FAQ link?

---

#### Example:

```
function Comp( {someCond} ) {
  const [counter, setCounter] = useState(0);

  if (someCond) {
    // we are setting derived state directly in render (see FAQ).
    setCounter(prev => prev + 1);
    // <-- imagine, at this point React aborts this render (and restarts later)
    // Does it lead to inconsistencies?
  }

  // ... return some jsx
}
```

Comment: Hi, why should it be problematic? Could you express better what causes your slight feeling, please?

Comment: In concurrent mode, a render can potentially be aborted and restarted. I am curious, if that causes problems, if state is changed directly in the render phase as in this case. Let's assume, a render is restarted *after* we have set state. Is that a valid case/ supported by React or does it cause inconsistencies?

Comment: I think that the function call phase and the render phase are different (even if we generically call them "render") and so no inconsistencies happen

Comment: @NoriSte thanks, to clarify: By "function call phase" you mean calling the setter of `useState`? I also added code, so everyone can speak about the same example.

Comment: Thanks! I mean the "component function call", `Comp` in your example 

Comment: You can read more about the topic [in this amazing article](https://blog.isquaredsoftware.com/2020/05/blogged-answers-a-mostly-complete-guide-to-react-rendering-behavior/). In my comments I erroneously referred to the render phase (I called it the "function call phase") and the commit phase (calling it the "render phase")

Answer (score 0):

It's safe, but you can only update the state of this component until you have no side-effect on other components during render. in react 16.13.0 a warning added about this.

react 16.13.0 [release note](https://reactjs.org/blog/2020/02/26/react-v16.13.0.html#warnings-for-some-updates-during-render):

> ## Warnings for some updates during render A React component should not
>
> cause side effects in other components during rendering.
>
> It is supported to call setState during render, but only for the same
> component. If you call setState during a render on a different
> component, you will now see a warning:
>
> ```
> Warning: Cannot update a component from inside the function body of a different component.
> ```

Comment: While I understand the words of the release note, I remain uncertain about the implications when writing an app implementing `useState` for component state (and lifting state), and `redux`. I keep getting this warning when I try to dispatch an update to my store intended to trigger side effects. I'll have to extract some code into a pen I guess, but I sure would like to have some better characterization of how I should be structuring my code to prevent this warning if anyone can help with that? For example, how would I know if another component is rendering?